# Performance hit when combining class member arrays to a single array

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, class, member

I'm trying to make my code a bit faster and I'm trying to find out if I can gain some performance by better managing arrays stored in objects and stuff.

So the basic idea behind that is that I tend to keep separate arrays for temporary and permanent states. This means that they have to be indexed separately all the time having to explicitly write the proper member name every time I want to use them.

This is how a particular class with such arrays looks like:

```
class solution
{
public:

    //Costs
    float *cost_array;
    float *temp_cost_array;
    //Cost trend
    float *d_cost_array;
    float *temp_d_cost_array;

    ...

}
```

Now, because of the fact that I have functions/methods that work on the temp or the permanent status depending on input arguments, these look like this:

```
void do_stuff(bool temp){
if (temp)
    work_on(this->temp_cost_array);
else
    work_on(this->cost_array);
}
```

These are very simplistic examples of such branches. These arrays may be indexed separately here and there within the code. So exactly because of the fact that such stuff is all over the place I thought that this is yet another reason to combine everything so that I could get rid of that code branches as well.

So I converted my class to:

```
class solution
{
public:

    //Costs
    float **cost_array;
    //Cost trend
    float **d_cost_array;
    ...

}
```

Those double arrays are of size 2, with each element being a float* array. Those are dynamically allocated just once during object creation at the start of the program and deleted at the end of the program.

So after that I also converted all the temp branches of my code like this:

```
void do_stuff(bool temp){
    work_on(this->cost_array[temp]);
}
```

It looks WAY more elegant than before but for some reason performance got way worse than before (almost 2 times worse), and I seriously can't understand why that happened.

So, as a first insight, I'd really love to hear from more experienced people, if my rationale behind that code optimization was valid or not.

Could that extra indexing required to access each array introduce such major performance hit to overcome all the if branching and stuff? For sure it depends on how the whole thing works but the code is a beast and I've no idea how to properly profile that thing all-together.

Thanks

EDIT:

Environment settings:
Running on Windows 10, VS 2017, Full Optimization enabled (/Ox)

Comment: Do you have optimizations enabled? What compiler flags are you using?

Comment: Its visual studio I've set it up to full optimization /Ox

Comment: How are you allocating your arrays?

The number of allocs will directly affects performance.

Comment: @GregK. How are you measuring performance?

Comment: *t looks WAY more elegant than before but for some reason performance got way worse than before (almost 2 times worse), and I seriously can't understand why that happened.* -- You didn't mention the compiler and options you used to compile your code -- options such as optimizations used.  Second, over-pointerizing code doesn't necessarily make code faster -- when you do that, you befuddle the compilers optimizer, thus potentially making your code slower than it could be.

Comment: Try to minimize indirections. See if it makes your code more cache friendly. See if you can reduce the amount of dynamic allocation. Profile, analyse, benchmark, repeat.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The profiler within visual studio doesn't look very helpful so I'm just timing a common function with the two versions.

Comment: @Fracdroid the arrays within the solution class are allocated only once at creation. then the object is used and deleted after its done. There are no intermediate removals. However there are multiple copies included. But those were like thata before as well

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie that is sort of the morale I get from the story :/ I've commented a bit above about my flags and environment. Thanks for you insight.

Comment: So your operations do, in fact, result in new temp objects and their associated allocations/deallocation getting invoked? Maybe instead of float ** arrays, try float * array[2]?

Comment: Well you took branch prediction completely out of the equation, which is sometimes good, but in this case perhaps the predictor was right most of the time.

Comment: Way slower, on a single branch before an array operation? No way. It really sounds like you introduced a bug. You must have allocated/deallocated copies, or corrupted the lengths, or something. Oh, only double? Well maybe (he said dubiously).

Comment: @Fracdroid well theoretically yes, but in practice I just need one solution object and all operations are acting on this particular one for a while before it gets destroyed. As for the copies, they happen in an array and not in a solution level. So overall during the lifespan of the object (which is where the intensive operations are invoked) there are no allocations/deallocations performed. However, your idea is worth the try, I'll take a closer look. Thanks again

Comment: @AndyG I also thought of that, but sounded like a really stupid thought. The key point is that indeed there are long periods of working only on the temp parts and then some smaller periods of working on the permanent parts. After realizing that I think that indeed the branch prediction may in fact work like a charm in this case :O Is there any way to get feedback from the predictor?

Comment: @GregK.: You can instrument your code with something like PAPI to get branch mispredictions.

Comment: Echoing Fracdroid on `float* array[2]`, or if you have need for this type of temp pattern a lot, maybe generalize it to its own class where you can centrally experiment to find the optimal solution. My conjecture (and being conjecture, it could be completely wrong) is that your optimizer was actually eliminating the `if (temp)` branch all along. It may have had enough info at compile-time to inline that function and eliminate the branch. If that's the case, all you effectively did was introduce another layer of pointer indirection.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for such a huge performance degradation might be that with the change we have introduced another level of indirection, accessing which might slow down the program quite significantly.

The object prior the change:

```
*array -> data[]
*temp_array -> data[]
```

Assuming the object (i.e. `this`) is in the CPU cache, prior the change you had one cache miss: take either of the pointers from cache (cache hit) and access a cold data (cache miss).

The object after the change:

```
**array -> * -> data[]
           * -> data[]
```

Now we have to access pointer to an array (cache hit) then index the cold data (cache miss) then access the cold data (another cache miss).

Sure, that is the worst scenario described above, but it might be the case.

The fix is quite easy: allocate those pointers in the object with `float *cost_array[2]`, not dynamically, i.e.:

```
*array[2] -> data[]
          -> data[]
```

So in therms of storage and levels of indirections this is exactly corresponds to the original data structure prior the change and should behave quite the same.